# WPF menu like control showing when clicking a control ;) How?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I have an application that connects to a server. In the status bar I show the connection status, and on a click I want to open a "menu like" subcontrol over the status showing control where more detailed connection information is shown (like: user name, server name, ping delay, disconnect / reconnect button).

This should basically look like an inverse menu - and when the user clicks outside of that area, the outside click should be suppressed (not triggering anything), but the detail info box should disappear.

I am a little at a loss here - first time I am to do something like that in WPF.

- Which control would be advisable as base here? So far I have a custom control for the status bar - but basically it renders as a text box. Note tha the popup is not a menu - it should show a detailed view of the control, so I do not think I can reuse any existing control.
- any Hints how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two controls to look into:
  1.  Expander (this could work, but be carefull, it can shift your other controls
2.  Button with template. Make a controltemplate for a button that includes a Popup item. This item can then be bound to a set of triggers/events in the button or in the wider form. I hope this helps :)

Comment: 1 is out - givne the soriginal control lives on the status bar, basically, it is VERY small (how much text does "Connected" take?). You have some more links to the Popup item stuff you mention?

Comment: Found it - there actually is a PopUp control in WPF ;) Nice. THanks.

Comment: No prob, soz i couldnt get on and comment back, was doing something. Hope this works for you :)